# Binary safe bash 'here string'?

Tags: bash, herestring

I'd like to save output of a command to a variable for later multiple uses. Bash provides [Here String](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) functionality for that purpose. However it is not binary safe. It sometimes adds new lines:

```
$ a=''
$ xxd <<< "$a"
00000000: 0a
```

**Is there any binary safe alternative?**

I use the variable in for loop so IIUIC it disqualifies `tee` command and any pipe like solution. I'd also prefer something else than temporary files as the are slow and clumsy to work with (require a writable directory, clean-up).

Comment: Bash variables aren't binary-safe to begin with (they can't contain `NUL`s, for instance), so as long as you're fetching the data from a variable, you have already disqualified it. Is it the newline specifically that you want to strip?

Comment: @Dolda2000 This is not true. Bash variables *can* contain `NUL` bytes. Try `a="a\0b"; echo -en "$a" | xxd`

Comment: @hek2mgl: Then please explain why the following command prints "6" rather than "7": `foo="$(base64 -d <<<"Zm9vAGJhcgo=")"; echo ${#foo}`

Comment: @hek2mgl: As for your `echo -en` example, the variable does not store any `NUL`, it simply stores `\0`, literally. It is `echo` that replaces that with a `NUL` since you gave it the `-e` option.

Comment: Indeed, `${#a}` gives `4`.

Comment: @Dolda2000 My problem is that `wc -l <<< "$a"` is not reliable. It returns one line even if the variable is empty. But I'm also curious what is a general solution. I don't need to use variables. If they are no suitable for that purpose, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what, exactly, it is that you need. If your problem is only the newline that here-strings add, then all you need is `echo -n`:

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo -n "$foo" | od -t x1
0000000 62 61 72
```

If you need to preserve the trailing newline(s) that command-substitution strips, or you truly need full binary safety, however, then there are no "work-arounds", unfortunately. Command-substitution will always strip trailing newline no matter what, and as mentioned in the comments, shell variables are not binary safe as they cannot contain `NUL`s. If you need any of those things, then I'm pretty sure your only option is using temporary files.

As for using temporary files, however, the problem you state of finding a writable directory *should* be a small one, as `/tmp` is always guaranteed to be writable by all unless you're working on a *really* weird system, or your script is supposed to run during an incomplete or failed boot, perhaps. In that case, you'll just have to switch to C instead. Otherwise, just use the `mktemp` command. As for cleanup, you may want to use the `trap` built-in command.